# What powers does a Whip actually have to force MP's to vote their way?

Tags: united-kingdom, parties, parliament

In the UK especially we have a parliamentary democracy, and each of the major political parties have an officer known as the [Whip/Chief Whip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whip_(politics)), who as far as I understand enforce party policy, by compelling MP's to vote their way.

Now I'm purely using him as an example but the current Leader of the Labour Party [Jeremy Corbyn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremy_Corbyn), "defied the whip" [428 times](http://revolts.co.uk/?p=914) when he was an MP. similarly [47 Labour MP's defied a "three line Whip"](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2017/feb/01/a-fifth-of-labour-mps-defy-three-line-whip-to-vote-against-article-50-bill) (which I understand is more serious) during the bill to trigger [Article 50](http://www.lisbon-treaty.org/wcm/the-lisbon-treaty/treaty-on-European-union-and-comments/title-6-final-provisions/137-article-50.html). This process of defying the whip seems awfully commonplace, so is their any actual point to "whipping" in the first place?

As such **my questions are**:

**What powers does a whip have to enforce the party line?** (or why does anyone listen to the whip?)

- As such what are the consequences of defying a 1,2 and 3 line whip?

Comment: @Bobson I dispute that they are duplicates, one question is very specific about 3 line whips, and the answer largely rests on comply or face the consequences. This question refers to the general powers of a whip and also includes 1 and 2 line whips.

Comment: You're right. In that case, https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/11562/how-do-whips-enforce-control-over-mps-in-the-uk-parliament/ is a better duplicate target.